# NodeJS gm - composite image from memory

Tags: node.js, imagemagick, imagick, composite, graphicsmagick

I have previously written the following command in PHP in order to merge two fies using php imagick.

```
$canvasImg->compositeImage($overlayImg, Imagick::COMPOSITE_OVER, $x, $y);
```

Now I'm trying to do the same using nodejs GraphicsMagic. But the gm.composite('path.jpg', callback) only accepts file paths. I have created a pretty complex image that I have in memory that I want to use like the example in PHP, so saving it to disk in order to merge it is not an option (I'm using it in a nested loop so there can be a lot of mergings).

So, is there any way of using the objects from memory and composite them together?

Comment: maybe try reading the image once into a readStream/writeStream?

Comment: I already have them in memory, so I don't have to read anything, I just want to composite the two images from memory instead of from file path. Like the example in PHP.